# How to get a JSON with dollar sign

Tags: android, json, dollar-sign

suppose I have `{"data": {"243232": {"id": "testid","name": "test" } }}`

so how to get correct value thanks.

Comment: What does this have to do with the dollar sign? You just want to parse the JSON-String?

Comment: what do you mean by "correct value" and "dollar sign"? JQuery?? Since you tag "android", you may need a java JSON library : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library

Comment: the problem is that attributes must begin with a letter not a numerical sign like $, this is a special case, i don't no how to get the value (get("$") don't work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant directly pass above String with Gson as *"243232"* is number and we cant declare variable which start from number, So for parsing this you must modify the string with some notification

i.e. `{"data": {"temp243232": {"id": "testid","name": "test" } }}`

here i modified string manually *"243232"* by *"temp243232"*, now you can parse it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JSON parser for Java like [Google GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). This works best if the class whose object your data in json represents, is known to you.

```
String str = ""; //contains your json string
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyClass var = gson.fromJson(str,MyClass.class);
```

where MyClass will be a class which represents the object.
Then you can access data just like you'd do from a data structure in your program, it'll be something like `var.data`.

Comment: I am using Gson but the problem is that $ is not accepted (@SerializedName("$")) how could i do it.